# vue.js how to bind classes to plugin component generated elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I use [Vuejs-datatable](https://vuejs-datatable.patrickstephan.me/) pluggin for the pagination in my page.
There I have to code

```
<datatable-pager v-model="page" type="long" :per-page="per_page"></datatable-pager>
```

will generate a code like this

```
<nav>
<ul class="pagination">
    <li>
        <a><a/>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a><a/>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a><a/>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**What I want is to bind a class for `<a>` elements** How can I achieve this using vue.js.

Comment: Why do you want class in `<a>` element? Do you want to apply css?

Comment: Not to apply css. I want to directly call bootstrap classes page item for <li> and page-link for <a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a whole lot you can do to add classes to elements that deep inside a premade component unless you fork the codebase for said codebase on github and modify it to make it possible.
An alternative would be to add a class to the actual component itself and then use css selectors to affect those elements.

To do so you might do something like:

```
.pagination li a {
  // Styles affecting the a element here
}
```

Having looked through the documentation for Vue Datatable, it appears as if you can add custom templates for the tables but not the table pager component.

Comment: I have found something like this in the main.js where I register this plugin "Vue.use(DatatableFactory);" I clicked this while pressing control key then I navigate through some files and found settings.js there I had a parameter to give class names to <a> and <li>. I think your correct vue.js dosen't have way to handling this problem we have to go with the code base. =)